# How do I smoothly clamp controller input?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, smoothing, lerp, clamp

I'm trying to rotate an object according to the stick input on a controller, and then clamp it at a maximum rotation. When I use `Mathf.Clamp()` the rotation just hits that wall, and it doesn't feel good.  I've tried using `Mathf.SmoothDamp()` as well and that creates similar results.  Is there a way to smoothly approach the max rotation angle while taking the stick input into account?

```
    void Update()
    {
        SmoothRotate();
    }

    void SmoothRotate()
    {
        rotateX += iR.leftStickY * rotationSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        rotateX = Mathf.Clamp(rotateX, -maxPitchAngle, maxPitchAngle);
        currentRotX = Mathf.Lerp(currentRotX, rotateX, .5f);

        rotateZ += iR.leftStickX * rotationSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        rotateZ = Mathf.Clamp(rotateZ, -maxPitchAngle, maxPitchAngle);
        currentRotZ = Mathf.Lerp(currentRotZ, rotateZ, .5f);

        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(currentRotX, currentAngle.y, currentRotZ);
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this Stuff**

```
 public float mouseSensitivity = 10.0f;
 public Transform target;
 public float dstFromTarget = 2.0f;
 public float yaw;
 public float pitch;
 public Vector2 pitchMinMax = new Vector2(-50, 85);
 public float rotationSmoothTime = 0.02f;
 Vector3 rotationSmoothVelocity;
 Vector3 currentRotation;


 void Update()
 {
     SmoothRotate();
 }

 void SmoothRotate()
 {
     //Mouse Movement
     yaw += iR.leftStickX * mouseSensitivity;
     pitch -=  iR.leftStickY * mouseSensitivity;
 
     // Clamp
     pitch = Mathf.Clamp(pitch, -maxPitchAngle, maxPitchAngle);

  
     transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.SmoothDamp(currentRotation, new Vector3(pitch, yaw), ref rotationSmoothVelocity, rotationSmoothTime);
   

 }
```

Comment: So this works great on the x-axis when pitching forward, but when pitching back, things start spinning erratically.  The z-axis also isn't getting clamped and can spin as much as it likes. I changed yaw to roll, as the rotation is around the z-axis and added `roll = Mathf.Clamp(roll, -maxPitchAngle, maxPitchAngle);` to clamp it.